# How do you guys use doxygen?

Tags: init-file, c++, c, documentation

I'm curious about Doxygen, how do you guys manage documentation in C/C++ projects on emacs? I didn't find a good package that does it consistently. So far I did use [gendoxy](https://github.com/mp81ss/gendoxy) and [doxymacs](https://github.com/pniedzielski/doxymacs). I had problems with gendoxy related to function commentaries, there is a bug when the function returns different of void and there is some parameter, the last parameter is seen as output. After that, I did try doxymacs and it worked well, but the problem is that I don't know how to customize somethings, for example in function commentaries I would like to use "@brief" above the parameters, there isn't this tagging.

Comment: This question doesn't properly describe what "manage documentation" means.

Comment: I'm talking about code documentation, Doxygen and etc. How do you guys use Doxygen? What package manage this?

Comment: It's still unclear, what would a package that manages doxygen do?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking about packages which *generate* doxygen comments?

Comment: exactly @npostavs!